# Will a running process in an EC2 instance accessed through Session Manager be terminated if my local machine shuts down?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-session-manager

I am using Windows and connecting to a Linux EC2 instance via Session Manager.

The instance has an S3 bucket mounted, I am running a heavy decompression operation which writes output to the S3 bucket, and this could take over a day to complete. (**Clarifying: This operation is taking place inside the EC2 instance**)

I have not used session manager before so I am unsure about this: If my Windows PC shuts down, will the decompression operation also get cancelled or will it keep running as long as the instance is in active status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will get canceled when you disconnect. Therefore, you could use   [tmux](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki) or [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). Having those, you lunch your program in these "shells" and it will keep running after you log out or loose connection.

There is also [nohup](https://linux.101hacks.com/unix/nohup-command/) and [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/) which could also be helpful.